# Ending conversation

Tags: node.js, chatbot, botframework

My bot (using MS BotFramework) is supposed to be hearing the conversation stream. If someone mentions 'chatbot' it should say 'Here I am!', otherwise stays quiet. It seems to be very simple and maybe it is but I am having a hard time trying to implementing it. Here is what I have:

```
bot.add('/', function(session) {
  if (someoneSaidChatbot) {
    session('Here I am!")
  } else {
    // session.reset(), maybe? No!
    // session.endDialog() then? Uh...nope.
    // nothing? Hmmm. negative
  }
});
```

So, nothing works. If I leave there the bot just hangs and it stops listening to the stream or answering commands. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code ends a dialog when someone types "chatbot" as part of the utterance.  Is this what you are looking for?

```
bot.add('/', function (session) { 
    if (session.message.text.search("chatbot") >= 0) {
        session.endDialog("Here I am");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest use `endConversationAction()` to register a  Bots Global Actions

```
bot.endConversationAction(
      'enddialog',                 //dialog Id
      'Here I am',                 //message
      { matches: /^.*chatbot/i }   //match pattern
    );
```

since this is global action, anytime when bot heard "Chatbot", it will say "Here I am" , if there are some dialog in stack, your proposed solution might not work.

Answer (score 0):

It may also depend on which channel you're using.  Some channels don't offer the ability for the Bot to listen to all of the messages in the conversation.